# Check If TextField is Equal to an Element in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, textfield

I have the user type in to a TextField in an Applet which I want to check that the String they typed is equal to the corresponding element in the ArrayList of answers, however I get a large compile time error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.game.main.AppletMain.actionPerformed(AppletMain.java:72) // etc
```

Here is the code, Main class (I have edited out unimportant parts:

```
private TextField commandInput;
private TextArea messageDisplay;
private Message messages;
private Answer answers;
private int currentLevel;

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String userInput = commandInput.getText();
    if (userInput == answers.getIntroAnswers().get(0)) {
        messageDisplay.append("\n \n" + userInput + "\n \n");
        commandInput.selectAll();
    }
    getCurrentLevel();
}
```

And here is the Answers class which holds the ArrayList:

```
package com.game.main;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Answer {

private ArrayList<String> introAnswers;
private String introAns1 = "go", introAns2 = "Go";

public Answer() {
    introAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();
    introAnswers.add(introAns1);
    introAnswers.add(introAns2);
}

public ArrayList<String> getIntroAnswers() {
    return introAnswers;
}

}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you've created an instance of the Answer class, which would give you a null exception when you try to access the elements

Comment: You also compare Strings with == instead of equals, which is wrong. The stack trace tells precisely which line throws the exception, so you should be able to figure out what is null and shouldn't be in this line.

Comment: Thankyou. That's twice that's happened to me today, seems like it's an off day. And I have never had to use equals before as I'm still relatively new to Java but I looked into at and have now used it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a reference to an object of type `Answer` but you never assigned a new object to it

```
private Answer answers;
```

You could do this assignment in the constructor, just once, or you must create a new object every time you click the button.

I am assuming your class name is `Cons`:

```
public Cons(){
 answer = new Answer();
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you building your GUI? The error you are getting would lead me to guess you are not instantiating the Answers objects before trying to call methods on them. To fix this, make sure you have initialized the answers-variable to hold an instance of an Answer object.

Also, there is something to consider about comparing Strings.

== is the operator for comparing **reference equality**, which tests if both variables point to the same object. When comparing strings, **always use the equals()-method**. Like this:

```
String a = "asd";
String b = "asdasd";
String c = "asd";
a.equals(b); // would equal false
c.equals(a); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

String is an object therefore == only compares the references, not their contents. Try
: `answers.getIntroAnswers().get(0).equals(userInput)`

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what the others have said,before code runs into  "answers.getIntroAnswers().get(0)" which is what most say throws the exception which may be true,  I  also think "String userInput =commandInput.getText();" has a good chance of throwing the exception given that there's no initialization of that text field in the code provided...